# Schema Registry URL for IIDR CDC Kafka subscription

Tags: apache-kafka, cdc, ibm-infosphere, ibm-data-replication, amazon-msk

I have created a cluster Amazon MSK. Also, created an EC2 instance and installed Kafka on it to create a topic in Amazon MSK. I am able to produce/consume messages on the topic using Kafka scripts.

I have also installed the IIDR Replication agent on an EC2 instance. The plan is to migrate DB2 table data into the Amazon MSK topic.

In the IDR Management console, I am able to add the IIDR replication server as the target.
Now when creating the subscription, it is asking for ZooKeeper URL and Schema Registry URL. I can get the Zookeeper endpoints from Amazon MSK.

What value to provide for the schema registry URL as there's none created?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to specify a schema registry because say you are using a KCOP that generate JSON, just put in a dummy value. Equally if you are specifying a list of Kafka brokers in the kafkaconsumer.propertie and the kafkaproducer.properties files in the CDC instance.conf directory you can put in dummy values for the zookeeper fields.

Hope this helps

Robert

Comment: Yes I have specified bootstrap servers in kafkaconsumer.properties and the kafkaproducer.properties files. 
In the IDR Management console, I have specified dummy values for Zookeeper server and didn't provide any values for schema registry.

Zookeeper Server: Host Name: test Port: 2181
Schema Registry: Host Name: Port: 

It doesn't give any errors but the replication still fails in IDR management console